# Add Values from JTextFied to JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton, actionlistener

```
    public class BillDetailsPanel implements ActionListener {


        JPanel panel;
        int flag = 0;
        JLabel lItemName, lPrice, lQty, ltax, lDisPrice;
        JTextField price, qty, tax, disPrice;
        JComboBox<String> itemName;
        String[] bookTitles = new String[] { "Effective Java", "Head First Java",
                "Thinking in Java", "Java for Dummies" };

        JButton addBtn

        public BillDetailsPanel() {
            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 50));
            FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 15);
            panel.setLayout(layout);
            // panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

            lItemName = new JLabel("Item Name");
            lPrice = new JLabel("Price");
            lQty = new JLabel("Quantity");
            ltax = new JLabel("Tax");
            lDisPrice = new JLabel("Discount Price");

            itemName = new JComboBox<String>(bookTitles);
            itemName.addActionListener(this);
            price = new JTextField(8);
            // price.setEditable(false);
            qty = new JTextField(4);
            tax = new JTextField(5);
            // tax.setEditable(false);
            disPrice = new JTextField(8);

            addBtn = new JButton("Add");
            addBtn.addActionListener(this);

            panel.add(lItemName);
            panel.add(itemName);
            panel.add(lPrice);
            panel.add(price);
            panel.add(lQty);
            panel.add(qty);
            panel.add(ltax);
            panel.add(tax);
            panel.add(lDisPrice);
            panel.add(disPrice);
            panel.add(addBtn);
            panel.setVisible(true);

        }
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    BillTablePanel btp=new BillTablePanel();
            String[] data=new String[5];


            data[0]=(String) itemName.getSelectedItem();
data[1]=price.getText();
    data[2]=qty.getText();
    data[3]=tax.getText();
    data[4]=qty.getText();
    btp.model.addRow(data);
           btp.model.addRow(data);
            System.out.println(data+"dataaaaaaaaaaaa");     

        }

    }



    }


    public class BillTablePanel implements ActionListener{
        public JPanel panel;
        public JTable table;
        public JScrollPane scrollPane, scrollPane1;
        public DefaultTableModel model;
        public int a=10;
    String[] data=new String[5];
        public BillTablePanel () {

            panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(null);

            model = new DefaultTableModel();

            String columnNames[] = { "Item Name", "Actual Price", "Qty", "Tax",
                    "Price" };

            table = new JTable();
            model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
            table.setModel(model);
            table.setFocusable(false);
            scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
            scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 850, 100);

            panel.add(scrollPane);
        }

    <br>


    public class TestClassFrame {
        JFrame f;

        BillDetailsPanel bill = new BillDetailsPanel();
        BillTablePanel billTablePanel = new BillTablePanel();
        public TestClassFrame() {

            f = new JFrame("Zeon Systems");
            f.setLayout(null);

            bill.panel.setBounds(0, 0, 900, 100);

            f.add(bill.panel);
            billTablePanel.panel.setBounds(0, 100, 900, 500);
            f.add(billTablePanel.panel);
            f.pack();
            f.setSize(900, 550);
            f.setVisible(true);
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        }

         public static void main(String[] args) {
         new TestClassFrame();
         }

}
```

Problem with this code is The class Bill detais contain some text boxes and a button The BillTablepane class contain a Jtable I want to add the items from BillDetaisaPanel to the Jtable

On clicking the Jbutton which is not showing any error but the values are not inserting on it

The Full source is there Somebody please help me to find the logical error,

Comment: This is getting annoying. Creating a new userid to ask the same question that has been asked 3 times. You have been asked several times to post a SSCCE. You have been given suggestions on how to create a SSCCE. But you still continue to dump irrelevant code that doesn't compile. If you want to learn to problem solve, then you need to learn how to simplify problems.

Answer (score 2):

In your actionPerformed method, you're creating a new BillTablePanel object, at line (1), and then trying to add to the table model on line (2):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    BillTablePanel btp=new BillTablePanel();  // **** (1)
    // ...

    btp.model.addRow(data);  // ***** (2)
```

But understand that that new BillTablePanel is just that, a completely new and distinct object, one completely unrelated to the one that is displayed. To change the state of the displayed data, you must call methods on the displayed BillTablePanel object, not on a new one that you create just for the actionPerformed method.

For example, here's a similar minimal program:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableExample extends JPanel {
    private HoldsTable holdsTable = new HoldsTable();
    private JTextField lastNameField = new JTextField(10);
    private JTextField firstNameField = new JTextField(10); 

    public TableExample() {
        JPanel fieldPanel = new JPanel();
        fieldPanel.add(new JLabel("Last Name:"));
        fieldPanel.add(lastNameField);
        fieldPanel.add(new JLabel("First Name:"));
        fieldPanel.add(firstNameField);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Your Action") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                HoldsTable ht = new HoldsTable(); // creates a new reference -- bad!
                String lastName = lastNameField.getText();
                String firstName = firstNameField.getText();

                ht.addName(lastName, firstName);
            }
        }));
        buttonPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("My Action") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                // HoldsTable ht = new HoldsTable();
                String lastName = lastNameField.getText();
                String firstName = firstNameField.getText();

                // ht.addName(lastName, firstName);
                holdsTable.addName(lastName, firstName); // use the ref to the displayed object
            }
        }));

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(holdsTable, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(fieldPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TableExample mainPanel = new TableExample();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableExample");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}

class HoldsTable extends JPanel {
    private static final String[] COL_NAMES = { "Last Name", "First Name" };
    private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(COL_NAMES, 0);
    private JTable table = new JTable(model);

    public HoldsTable() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(table));
    }

    public void addName(String lastName, String firstName) {
        String[] row = { lastName, firstName };
        model.addRow(row);
    }
}
```

Your program creates a new **non-displayed** object, and changes its properties, similar to this code in my program above:

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            HoldsTable ht = new HoldsTable(); // creates a new reference --
                                              // bad!
            String lastName = lastNameField.getText();
            String firstName = firstNameField.getText();

            ht.addName(lastName, firstName);
        }
    }));
```

But since the object whose state is being changed, here `ht`, but in your code its `btp`, is not the one that is displayed, nothing will show.

The correct way is shown in the other action:

```
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            // HoldsTable ht = new HoldsTable();
            String lastName = lastNameField.getText();
            String firstName = firstNameField.getText();

            // ht.addName(lastName, firstName);
            holdsTable.addName(lastName, firstName); // use the ref to the
                                                     // displayed object
        }
```

I create a field of the GUI view that holds the JTable, here `holdsTable` and call a method on it. Since holdsTable is visible, changes in its state will be shown in the program (here the JTable).